# Correlated sub query detailed execution plan

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to understand ,how a correlated subquery works in detailed.I am executing below query  which gives the output i wanted,but i am having hard time trying to visualize how this is working

```
select top 5* from persons where personid in (select personid from tbpersons where Persons.ConsolidatedStatusID >50)
```

As per my understanding ,first inner query gets executed totally(virtual table 1) , the outerquery has to be executed to fetch rows which are having consolidated status >50(virtual table 2) and both will be compared,leaving VT1 with personids and outerquery will be executed.

This explanation doesn't fit my head actually, i am seeing table scan for tbpersons which i am ok with as per my understanding,but i should also see table scan for persons,which i am not seeing.

I was able to write it into a join,still not able to figure out ,how correlated subquery works

```
 select top 10 * from 
 persons rg
 join
tbpersons sy
 on sy.personid =rg.personid
 where rg.ConsolidatedStatusID>50
```

Can you please help me visualize how  execution takes place in step by step using virtual tables..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st of all your sub-query in 1st query is not a correlated sub-query. It is because it does not reference the outer query. It will be executed Before the outer Query and it will be executed only once. Then the results returned by the sub-query will passed to IN operator of the outer query.
Correlated Sub-Queries are executed for each record returned by the outer query and the syntax is something like ..

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 , ....
FROM Table_Name T1
WHERE Col3 > ( SELECT Col1
               FROM Table_Name2
               WHERE Col2 = T1.Col2)   --<--- Reference to the outer query
```

Now why your query is resulting in a table scan, it depends on the indexes available for your query and the operator being used in your query. By looking at the information provided by you about the query its difficult to answer the question that why a table scan will take place, If you have a covered query.

Comment: Edited now, can you plz explaim taking the context of my question

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, i am not sure , how it is wrong i am able to get data also